# Running asp.net WebAPI on server without having to install asp.net mvc 4 beta

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a simple http service using apicontroller and i want to upload it on server. But the problem is that i can't install asp.net mvc4 beta on server. Is there any workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [bin deploy MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).  (Link is for MVC3, but should work for MVC4 as well.)

Basically, you'll copy the necessary MVC assemblies in your project's bin folder, so there will be nothing extra to install on the server, and your host doesn't need to support it.

Comment: thanks Kyle. it worked great. Its just i had to deploy asp.net web api on server and i was of the view that asp.net mvc 4 beta is a dependency but in the end i had to remove system.web.mvc.dll from bin to make thins work

Comment: Why not just use the nuget instead of copying assemblies around?